# Is this a health improvent towards usable equipments or just a recommendation thing?

Tags: discussion

I have been sedentary for years now and here is how my life goes basically:

- wake up
- elevator
- car
- drive to work
- elevator
- desk
- small breaks after 2 to 3 hours of working in front of a PC
- get up do some exercises nothing major just like arms, neck, shoulders
- after 12 hours work elevator
- car
- drive home
- elevator
- sleep
- rinse repeat (except for half of Sat and entire Sun)

I've cut some information like break fast, shower, lunch, drink, going out, I don't smoke, and so on as I just wanted to give you a feel of it.

So to put it simple I would like to improve my conditioning with exercises at home after work. What I use to be able to do at easy such as running 1~2 KM I can barely do now which seems to me like a red flag, carrying things around for not so long destinations also make me tired easily.

The only health problem I have is that every now and then have some asthmatic attacks which I had since kid but are this days nearly controlled and very few.

I am almost 29 now and what I would like to do is buy an equipment that will allow me to recondition myself back in shape but I have no idea of what kind of exercises I should be doing and what kinda of equipments are worth having for the same.

I guess it's also worth mentioning I am not fat and am not looking to lose weight. I am 1,70cm and about 60~70kg or so I think haven't weighted myself in awhile now.

So I am not sure weather I am looking for a recommendation product here or help with what exercises I can be doing and what equipments I could be using for those.

- **So I would like to know weather my question is fit here or where would be a good start point to me?** Or what I could change to fit here or whatever advice you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not exactly a shopping recommendation question. I'm reading this question as a general and broad which does not fit the site. What I recommend for you is to search through the site first to see if there are similar questions that you can use as a baseline.

There are a few that have survived from the early days of the Fitness site that you can read. Many new questions that surface that are very similar to yours end up being closed as duplicates which is why I recommend using what information is present on the site already and then coming back with more specific questions.